# Calculate an average value from two columns af a same table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (ttable) which looks like this :

```
id    debut     fin     value
1       2        4        10
2       4        6        0
3       6        8        12
```

I would like to update the value with id n°2 by setting it to an average from the values of id n°1 and 3, by joining them on some fields (debut and fin).
I would like to get this :

```
id    debut     fin     value
1       2        4        10
2       4        6        11
3       6        8        12
```

... where id °2 got an average from 10 and 12 because its debut value equals id n°1 fin value (4) and its fin value equals id n°3 debut value (6). I was thinking about a self-join on the table, a bit like this :

```
update ttable
    set value = 
    avg(m1 + m2) as 
    (select t1.value as m1, t3.value as m2 
  from ttable t1, ttable t2, ttable t3 where t1.fin = t2.debut and where t2.fin = t3.debut)
```

But this doesn't work, since I can not save it into a function. I don't know how to get it right. 
Any idea ?

Comment: Actually, the script doesn't really illustrate what you want.  Would _would_ work would be to show us clear sample input and the expected output, along with a description of what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `lag`/`lead` [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-window.html).

```
update ttable as d
  set value = (s.lg + s.ld) / 2
from (
  select
    id,
    lag(value) over(order by id) as lg,
    lead(value) over(order by id) as ld
  from ttable
) as s
where d.id = s.id and
      d.value = 0 and
      s.lg is not null and
      s.ld is not null;
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce69a/3).

**Attempt #2:**

```
update ttable as d
  set value = (p.value + x.value) / 2
from ttable as p, ttable as x
where p.value > 0 and
      d.value = 0 and
      x.value > 0 and
      p.fin = d.debut and
      d.fin = x.debut;
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12231/24).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The window functions seem interesting but I probably wasn't clear enough : the ids of my values do not follow each other like the simplified exemple I have provided. Would it work anyway with the values of the columns "debut" and "fin" as links ?

Comment: Works like a charm. Ешё проще, всё работает. Спосибо большой !

Comment: @Arn, добро пожаловать на борт :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work, but I guess there's a simplier way :

```
update ttable as d
set value = (u.lg + v.ld) / 2
from (
select
d.id,
s.value as lg
from ttable d, ttable s
where d.fin = s.debut
) as u,
(
select
d.id,
t.value as ld
from ttable d, ttable t
where d.debut = t.fin
) as v

where d.id = u.id and
        d.id = v.id and
  d.value = 0 and
  u.lg is not null and
  v.ld is not null;
```